# Invalid Hook Call on axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

My error occurs when I try to send api requests with axios but do not see the same error sending the request with fetch.  I looked at several react-native applications and It looks like I am using the axios.get method similar to theirs and don't see what I am doing wrong. I am new to react native so maybe I am doing something naively.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

const Example = () => {

  const requestGoogle = () => {
    const url = 'https://google.com'
    axios.get(url) //fetch(url) no error
      .then(res => {
        alert(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err)
      })
  }
  return ( <
    View >
    <
    Button title = "Send"
    onPress = {
      () => requestGoogle()
    }
    /> <
    /View>
  );
}

export default Example
```

I get the following error when running the previous code:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Looking into each reason:

1. I confirmed that React and React Dom have same react version 16.13.1
2. I don't think I but maybe?
3. I confirmed that only one copy of app exists in the project following their steps

Comment: Can you please share the rest of you app code? In your shared example you don't seem to be calling any hook that could cause that error

Comment: So i'm not going crazy. I think that helped solve my problem. Once you confirmed its not in the component I thought where else might it be and realized my axios.intercepter was set up incorrectly. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Add the component in which you render the `Example` component.